# PHP Code to compress a image?

Tags: php, image, compression

Is there any code in php to compress an image?

Comment: Compress as in?  To an archive or reduce size?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, images are usually compressed, so it doesn't make too much sense to archive them.

Secondly, here is a list of what PHP has to offer for compressing and archiving:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.compression.php

[Zlib](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zlib.php) should be good.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with imagemagick like this:

```
exec("convert image.jpg -quality 80% image.jpg");
```

Comment: Note that this will make the image smaller in "physical" dimensions (width x height), which is not compression (smaller in byte size). Try `-quality` instead of `-resize` - note that lower-quality images are generally smaller but uglier.